# SQL Query to get only those rows with only 1 value in another column

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

[image: Sample Table]

I need a query to return only those ProjectID's that have only State=21.
i.e I want only ProjectID 2 & 5.

I do not want those records with ProjectID 1, 3, 4 & 6, because in those case, the state is also equal to other numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasoning goes like

- In a subselect, select all ProjectID's that have a state = 21
- In the outer select, retain only those ProjectID's that only have a state = 21 using a `HAVING` clause

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  ProjectID
FROM    table t1
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  ProjectID
          FROM    table
          WHERE   state = 21
        ) t2 ON t2.ProjectID = t1.ProjectID
GROUP BY
        ProjectID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Select all the projects with a single state value, which ('the value') is, by the way, equal to the specified one:

```
SELECT   ProjectID
FROM     atable
GROUP BY ProjectID
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
   AND   MAX(State) = @State
```

You can also use `MIN`, `SUM`, or `AVG` to check the value of `State` with the same effect (because it should be the only value).

Answer (score 1):

```
select ProjectID,count(State) from table group by ProjectID having count(state)=1;
```

Comment: @dev - does it do what you need? In that case, I have misinterpreted you question.